# VM using a secondary graphic card

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, virtual-machine, vmware

at the moment i have a dual monitor setup on my main PCIe gfx card.

I know that on windows it is almost impossible to have a second card (eg no thrills PCI card) running without having an SLI motherboard because of a driver issue. Well this was my conclusion after many weeks of research.

I was thinking...is it possible to use a VM in order to utilize the secondary card as the default video output to feed another monitor?

let me know if you want me to clarify

Thanks :)

Comment: Where did you get that idea from? I've set up dual monitors using separate cards under windows before. Before dual-head cards came about it was the only way to do it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor#More_than_two_monitors

Comment: ive been struggling to install the second PCI card in windows it just doesn't recognize it as an adaptor. I currently have a dual head GFX card witch serves 2 monitors but what i need is the third output to come from the secondary card

Comment: @Arthur can you be more specific about which motherboard this is and what cards you're trying to use?  Because @Andee is right - it's trivial on 99% of setups to install a second card, especially if it's identical.

Comment: Hi Shinrai, I have a Dell Dimensions e520, its an Intel board with a PCIe slot for the gfx and 2 additional PCI slots. hope this helps. thanks for the prompt reply :)

Comment: @Arthur - What's the video card currently in the PCIe slot?  That's the most important detail.  (Also, FYI for you, when you're responding to somebody do @, otherwise they won't get notified unless it's their question/answer.  I only happened to check back here or I'd never have seen your response.)

Comment: @Shinrai I can vouch for arthurs problem here... I have a friend with a C521 (very similar) I tried for couple hours to help him hook up a second 8400 in the PCI slot. Whatever board Dell used here just refuses to accept the second video card. In fact I thought the card was toast since the card would not work as a single PCI card... same card works fine in multiple other pc's. Must be something with that board since I run multiple cards in optiplex's fairly regularly.

Comment: Also I believe with that setup he is already running two GPU's ati x1300 & the onboard Nvida 6150 SE.

Comment: @Kyle - Ouch! Bizarre but there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

The VM will certainly output to a second monitor (I do this in the office), but for that to work the underlying PC will have to be supporting two monitors to start with anyway - and this is certainly very possible under Windows 7 using 'standard' (non SLI) graphics cards - my old desktop PC (Asus motherboard, I think - I don't have it any more) drove one monitor from its VGA port and a second from the DVI. Certainly a few motherboards do not like some mixes of cards and you should be able to find out what will work with a bit of Googling.

Comment: i have 2 monitors running from an ATI x1300 which is the maximum number of monitors that it supports. ive tried adding a second pci card but it doesn't get recognized at all. i searched around on google and it seems quite unclear whether this is possible or not. like I mentioned earlier i have fund some reference to the fact that windows has issues with more than one display driver.

Comment: @Arthur - That's wrong, it's certainly possible.  I've run SEVEN QUAD OUTPUT CARDS on a single Windows 7 machine before.  See my comment on the question.